# Autosizing row to its content in Webix

Tags: datatable, autosize, webix

I'm using Webix to create a datatable.
Some editable rows can contain big fragments of a text and what I need to do is to make it visible in spite of the text length.
Is it possible to adjust row height to the size of its content automatically?

For example, here's a short snippet that accompanies my question:

http://webix.com/snippet/993794e9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `view:"datatable"` define

```
on:{
    "onresize":webix.once(function(){ 
      this.adjustRowHeight("title", true); 
    })
  }
```

Your snippet after my correction
http://webix.com/snippet/f17ac179